# How do I access children data in JSON response using Javascript/GAS

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement, math, google-apps-script

I am trying to access children data from a Json response to use it in an **if** statement but i don't know-how. Anyone know how to do this?

Here is the screenshot of the response and I have circled the object I want to access. I want only the summation to happen if the approval has a value i.e. **status** needs to be pending or approved, otherwise, no calculation will happen.

[image]

Here is the code that I use but don't know how to access the *approaval={data=[{status}]* form the JSON so as to use it

```
function showTimeData() {

    var users = getUsers()
    var endpoint = 'users/';
    var time_array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

        var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + users[i].id + '/time_entries?fields=approvals' + '&from=' + from + '&to=' + to + '&auth=' + TKF_AUTH;
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        var info = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        var content = info.data;
        var total_hours = 0;


        for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {
            if (content.data.approvals.data.length > 0) {
                hoursTotal = 0;
            }
            total_hours += parseInt(content[j].hours);
        }


        Logger.log('User name: ' + users[i].display_name + ' ' + 'User id: ' + users[i].id + '  ' + 'total hours: ' + total_hours)
    }
```

Comment: what is the line which prints this log stretch ?

Comment: @dronte7, I am not sure I understand you correctly, but this is not meant to be printed or logged, just used as a condition for a calculation to happen. when I do Logger.log( content) then I get all the response data. Does this answer your question?

Comment: it seems to be that you need `content.data.approvals.data[0].status`

Comment: @dronte7, thanks for the suggestion, but when i use it it throws an error ** Cannot read property "approvals" from undefined. ** . what could be the problem?

Comment: Does your code work? that one, which you have posted above.
Could you share the result of `JSON.stringify(content)` ?

Comment: I did not stringify content, how do I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean? I suggested to check what the `content` is.
E.g. maybe you do not need to use `data` two times. Because actually you are trying to use `info.data.data.approvals.data[0].status`.
Maybe you should try `info.data.approvals.data[0].status` ?
Or even `info.data[0].approvals.data[0].status` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all. You need to fix the error(mentioned in the chat in comments):
Replace this

```
if (content.data.approvals.data.length > 0) {
  hoursTotal = 0;
}
```

with this

```
if (content[j].approvals.data.length > 0) {
  hoursTotal = 0;
}
```

---

Then what you need is:

```
content[0].approvals.data[0].status
```

or an array of `status`es:

```
content[0].approvals.data.map(el => el.status)
```

or an array of all `status`es:

```
content.map(el => el.approvals.data.map(it => it.status)).flat(1)
```

but last example will work only in fairly new browsers.

Comment: I have tried this but it keeps throwing an error **TypeError: Cannot read property "approvals" from undefined**

Comment: @levi Could you share the result of `JSON.stringify(content)` ?

Comment: Am still learning Javascript and not sure how to go about this, could you kindly show me how to do it?

Comment: @levi You can write `console.log(JSON.stringify(content))` or `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(content))`

Comment: Thanks @dronte7 . I have updated my question with the screenshot of the stringified content, please check and advise

Comment: @levi, it seems to be, that you should use `content[0].approvals.data[0].status`, if you have printed `JSON.stringify(content)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206653/discussion-between-levi-and-dronte7).